# Face problem to create camera relative Movement in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started study on this from past few weeks. I I try to create character movement script in unity on 3d model, I want player follow camera continuously but it only follows when I release the forward button and again pressed it.

```
void Awake()
    {
        cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
        
        playerInput = new PlayerInput();
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        isRunningHash = Animator.StringToHash("isRunning");
        isSprintingHash = Animator.StringToHash("isSprinting");
        isJumpingHash = Animator.StringToHash("isJumping");
        isAttackingHash = Animator.StringToHash("isAttack");
        
        playerInput.Movement.Move.started += onMovementInput;
        playerInput.Movement.Move.canceled += onMovementInput;
        playerInput.Movement.Move.performed += onMovementInput;
        playerInput.Movement.Run.started += onRun; 
        playerInput.Movement.Run.canceled += onRun;
        playerInput.Movement.Jump.started += onJump;
        playerInput.Movement.Jump.canceled += onJump;
        playerInput.Movement.Attack.started += onAttack;
        playerInput.Movement.Attack.canceled += onAttack;   

        setJumpVariable();

    }

 void Update()
    {
        handleAnimation();
        handleRotation();
        handleAttacking();
    
        if(cooldownStart)
        {
            attackCountSpeed = attackCountSpeed  + 1 * Time.deltaTime ; 
            //Debug.Log(attackCountSpeed);
        }
        if(attackCountSpeed > 2.0f)
        {
            cooldownStart = false;
            attackCountSpeed = 1f;
            attackCount = 0;
        }

   
        if(isRunPressed )
        {   
        appliedMovement.x = currentRunMovement.x;
        appliedMovement.z = currentRunMovement.z;
           
        }
        else
        {
        appliedMovement.x = currentMovement.x;
        appliedMovement.z = currentMovement.z; 
        }
        if(isAttackAnimate && Attack_2Animate && !stopMove)
        {
        characterController.Move(appliedMovement  * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        handleGravity();
        handleJump();

    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        playerInput.Movement.Enable();
    }
    void OnDisable()
    {
        playerInput.Movement.Disable();   
    }
}
```

I also try camera relative movement part cut from onMovementInput function and paste it in another function and call it in update function after applying this camera relative movement work properly but gravity and Jumping function not working. I expect player will follow camera continuously and Jump and gravity also. Character Controller Component and New Input System used in this script.

```
void setJumpVariable()
    {
        float timeToApex = maxJumpTime /2;
        Gravity = (-2 * maxJumpHight / Mathf.Pow(timeToApex ,2));
        initialJumpingVelocity = (2 * maxJumpHight) / timeToApex;
    }

    void handleJump()
    {
        if(!isJumping && characterController.isGrounded && isJumpPressed)
        {
            animator.SetBool(isJumpingHash, true);
            isJumpAnimating = true;
            isJumping = true;
            currentMovement.y = initialJumpingVelocity;
            appliedMovement.y = initialJumpingVelocity;
        }
        else if(isJumping && characterController.isGrounded && !isJumpPressed)
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }

    void onJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        isJumpPressed = context.ReadValueAsButton();
    }

    void handleGravity()
    {
        bool isFalling = currentMovement.y <= 0.0f || !isJumpPressed;
        float fallMultiplier = 2.0f;
        
        if(characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            if(isJumpAnimating)
            {
                animator.SetBool(isJumpingHash, false);
                isJumpAnimating = false;

            }
            currentMovement.y = GroundedGravity;
            appliedMovement.y = GroundedGravity;
        }
        else if(isFalling)
        {
            float previousYVelocity = currentMovement.y;
            currentMovement.y = currentMovement.y + (Gravity * fallMultiplier * Time.deltaTime);
            appliedMovement.y = Mathf.Max((previousYVelocity + currentMovement.y) * 0.5f, -20f);
        }
        else
        {
            float previousYVelocity = currentMovement.y;
            currentMovement.y = currentMovement.y + (Gravity * Time.deltaTime);
            appliedMovement.y = (previousYVelocity + currentMovement.y) * 0.5f;
        }
    }

void onMovementInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
            currentMovementInput = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
            
    }
 void handleMovement()
    {
        currentMovement.x = currentMovementInput.x * moveSpeed;
        currentMovement.z = currentMovementInput.y * moveSpeed;
        currentRunMovement.x = currentMovementInput.x * RunSpeed;
        currentRunMovement.z = currentMovementInput.y * RunSpeed;
        isMovementPressed = currentMovementInput.x != 0 || currentMovementInput.y != 0;
        currentMovement = currentMovement.x * cameraTransform.right.normalized + currentMovement.z * cameraTransform.forward.normalized;
        currentRunMovement = currentRunMovement.x * cameraTransform.right.normalized + currentRunMovement.z * cameraTransform.forward.normalized;
    }
 void Update()
    {
        handleAnimation();
        handleRotation();
        handleAttacking();
    
        if(cooldownStart)
        {
            attackCountSpeed = attackCountSpeed  + 1 * Time.deltaTime ; 
            //Debug.Log(attackCountSpeed);
        }
        if(attackCountSpeed > 2.0f)
        {
            cooldownStart = false;
            attackCountSpeed = 1f;
            attackCount = 0;
        }

   
        if(isRunPressed )
        {   
        appliedMovement.x = currentRunMovement.x;
        appliedMovement.z = currentRunMovement.z;
           
        }
        else
        {
        appliedMovement.x = currentMovement.x;
        appliedMovement.z = currentMovement.z; 
        }
        if(isAttackAnimate && Attack_2Animate && !stopMove)
        {
        characterController.Move(appliedMovement  * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        handleGravity();
        handleJump();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CineMachine to make the camera follow your Player. In case you want to do it from code then Kindly mention the part at which the camera position is changing.

Comment: I actually used the CineMachine to camera follow my player but I actually want that player forward where the camera is facing or looking it actually work when I call handleMovement function in the update function but because of it my gravity and jump not work. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).